# Writing a formula using summation/sigma notation

Tags: summation

I seem to be having a problem with writing a general sigma notation for my case.

In this example, I am trying to sell a product on multiple markets (based on the customer's needs), but for each market the customer chooses, he shall get an additional 20% discount.

If he chooses only one market the price is `n`

If he chooses two markets, the price should be `n + n*0.1`

Three, `n + n*0.1 + n*0.2`

Sorry for noob question, help is appreciated

Edit:

Clarification - I am selling a product on five markets. If a customer wants to buy my product, he can choose to do so on all of the five markets.
For each market except the first, he will get a +10% discount on the purchase.

Example - Customer decides to buy the product on 4 markets. The price (on one market) is \$1. The customer's price shall then be \$1 (first) + \$0.9 (second) + \$0.8 (third) + \$0.7 (fourth) equaling to $3.4.

Another customer buys the product on 2 markets. The price is also \$1. His final price will be \$1 + \$0.9 = \$1.9

Also it is 10%, and not 20% as noted by Barry Cipra.

Comment: I can give you the summation notation, but I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. Suppose the price for one market is n=\$1. Then, according to your formula, the price for two markets is \$1.10, and the price for three markets is \$1.30. The price is getting higher; how is that a discount? Did you perhaps mean that the price for the second market it \$0.90 and the price for the third market is \$0.80?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely correct. Sorry for my bad wording

Comment: It's still confusing. If I choose three markets, do I then pay \$0.80 for products for all of the markets? Or do I pay \$1.00 for products in the first market, \$0.90 for products in the second market, and \$0.80 for products in the third market? If it's the latter, then how do you decide which market is "first", which is "second" and so on. As a buyer, I'd want the third market to be whichever I'm ordering the most products for, as that gives me the lowest price. But that might change from one order to the next.

Comment: And if there are 11 markets, are the products in the 11th market free? If there are more than 11 markets, do you start paying people to order products?

Comment: Uhh, I forgot some details, there can only be up to 5 markets. And for the buyer's choice, there is none lol. If you decide to buy the product on three different markets for example, the product will cost $1.00 on the first, $0.90 on the second and $0.80 on the third.

Comment: I suspect that wombat is writing an answer; can you edit your question to reflect the clarifications and additional details?

Comment: The expressions you've written don't make a lot of sense (to me, at least); they make it look as if the price is going *up*, not down, when the customer chooses multiple markets. It might be better to show a made-up example, with some actual dollar amounts, in which customer A chooses one market, B chooses two, and C chooses three. What does each customer wind up paying for their order(s)?

Comment: Also, the text talks about an "additional 20% discount" for each market chosen, but other things seem to suggest a 10% change.

Comment: I did edit it now, sorry my bad explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p$ be the base price for the product.

Assume the customer orders $n_1$ products for the first market,
$n_2$ products for the second market,
and so on, up to $n_N$ products for the $N$th market
($N \le 5$).
The amount you invoice them for is

$p \sum_{i=1}^N n_i \frac{11-i}{10}$

Ex: $p=\$7$, $N=3$, $n_1=5, n_2=4, n_3=2$.
The total is

$7 * (5*1.00 + 4*0.90 + 2*0.80) \approx \$71.40$

Comment: This is correct, thank you